# Segmentation fault | calculating factorial | Out of Index

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, segmentation-fault, indexoutofboundsexception

I have been getting this segmentation fault in many problems that I solve on online IDE's, but am not able to completely understand this issue and thus resolve it. Kindly help me with the same.

I understand it can occur due to stack overflow sometimes, therefore, I should use heap memory. But how to do that?

One example is for this code of finding factorials of large numbers

**Code**

```
// calculate factorial of really large numbers

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 500

int multiply(int arr[], int x, int len)
{
    int carry = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int temp = 0;


 
        for(; i < len; i++)
        {
            // multiply each digit w the number x and store the carry to be added in the next number
            temp = 0;
            temp = x * arr[i] + carry;
            arr[i] = (temp%10);
            carry = temp/10;
        }
    
        // if end carry is also generated, even that has to be accomodated in the ans
        while(carry != 0)   //18    === 8 1
        {
            temp = carry%10;
            carry /= 10;
            arr[i] = temp;
            len++;
        i++;
    }
    // final length of the number is returned so that it can be printed easily
    return len;
}

void factorial(int n)
{
    int arr[MAX];
   

     // The array initially contains 1
        arr[0] = 1;
        int arrLeng = 1;

    // multiply the nth number with n+1 to obtain the factorial
    for(int i = 2; i <=n; i++)
        arrLeng = multiply(arr, i, arrLeng);

    // print the final ans array though in reverse order
    for(int i = arrLeng-1; i >= 0; i--)
        cout<<arr[i];
    cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
// input the number
int n;
cin>>n;

    // call the main function
    factorial(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: btw i have tried to use dynamic array, that too gives same error. I used int *arr = new int[MAX];

Comment: How large is "large"? 500 digits is enough for 253!, but not more.

Comment: @molbdnilo the question says n<=500. so should i increase the value of MAX?

Comment: 500! has 1135 decimal digits.

Comment: 1135 values in array i.e setting MAX value to 1135 seems odd. That's a lot for stack memory. Btw still getting the same error

Comment: put check on index, it should not be greater than MAX

Comment: Don't use array.  Use `std::vector`.  The `std::vector` can grow during run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrLeng` crossing the limit of Hardcoded MAX 500.

You should always have a check on the index. It should not cross the MAX limit. This is not the problem of memory allocation on stack or heap.